# How to mapping joined collection to anonymous objects or namedtupple collections?

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

Are you know tools for mapping dict to anonymous object with inner collection?

I have some source of data:

```
data = [
    {
        "SpacehipId": 1,
        "SpacehipName": "Independence",
        "OfficerId": 1,
        "OfficerName": "John Smith"
    },
    {
        "SpacehipId": 1,
        "SpacehipName": "Independence",
        "OfficerId": 2,
        "OfficerName": "Steven Smith"
    },
    {
        "SpacehipId": 2,
        "SpacehipName": "Liberty",
        "OfficerId": 3,
        "OfficerName": "Michel Smith"
    }
]
```

And I need a function that will take this data, and return objects with which I can work something like this:

```
mapping = [
    { 
        "objectName": "spaceShip", 
        "keys": ["SpacehipId","SpacehipName"]
    }, 
    {   
        "objectName": "spaceShip.Crew", 
        "keys": ["OfficerId","OfficerName"]
    }
]

result = blackboxfunction(data, mapping)
```

Result of blackboxfunction function work, will be just like this:

```
>>> print(result[0].SpacehipId)
1
>>> print(result[1].Crew[0].OfficerName)
Michel Smith
```

What the tools and lib I should use for implement blackboxfunction?

Comment: Show us your implementation of `blackboxfunction`. Does it work?

Comment: The fact of the matter is that I want to know with what tools I can implement it.

Comment: where do u get this "objectName": "spaceShip", from ?

Comment: @toheedNiaz Query result from db

Comment: @toheedNiaz Sorry, previous comment is wrong. "spaceShip" and "spaceShip.Crew" just aliases for object names.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong "SpacehipName" in data is mapped as  objectName in mapping ? or if you can create the desired output based on `data` that will be great

Comment: "objectName" is name of object, "SpacehipName" name of object's attribute.

Comment: @Lutz Horn Your right. But I do not request solution. Just tools or libs, through which I could solve by himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Object():   
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.__dict__ = data

def groupBy(data, fields):
    hashes = {}
    items = {}
    for d in data:  
        group = {g: d[g] for g in d.keys() if g in fields}        
        h = sum([hash(d[value]) for value in group])
        if hashes.get(h) == None:
            hashes[h] = group

        item = {f: d[f] for f in d.keys() if f not in fields}
        if items.get(h) == None:
            items[h] = []
        items[h].append(item)

    return [{**hashes[h], **{'data': items[h]}} for h in hashes]

def joinedDictToObjects(data, mapping):
    mappedFields = [field for m in mapping for field in mapping[m]]
    groupFields = [field for field in data[0].keys() if field not in mappedFields]
    grouped = groupBy(data, groupFields)

    result = []    
    for g in grouped:
        objRaw = {key: g[key] for key in g if key not in ['data']}
        for m in mapping:
            objRaw[m] = [Object({a: g['data'][i][a] for a in g['data'][i] if a in mapping[m]}) for i, item in enumerate(g['data'])]
        result.append(Object(objRaw))

    return result
```

Using:

```
mapping = { "Crew": ["OfficerId", "OfficerName"] }
result = joinedDictToObjects(data, mapping)
```

Out:

```
>>> print(result[0].SpacehipId)
1
>>> print(result[1].Crew[0].OfficerName)
'Michel Smith'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `namedtuple` collection, which will then support your preferred syntax.

```
from collections import namedtuple


Spaceship = namedtuple('Spaceship', 'spaceshipID spaceshipName officerID officerName')

x = Spaceship(1, "Independece", 1, "John Smith")
x.spaceshipName
```

Even simpler you can define this function to convert any dictionary to a `namedtuple`:

```
def convert(dictionary, name):
    return namedtuple(name, dictionary.keys())(**dictionary)
```

then use it like:

```
d = {
        "SpacehipId": 2,
        "SpacehipName": "Liberty",
        "OfficerId": 3,
        "OfficerName": "Michel Smith"
    }

convert(d, "Spaceship")
```

So you can easily transform all your data using:

```
[convert(d, "Spaceship") for d in data]
```

Comment: x does not contains Crew list for officers

Comment: Result of "convert" does not contains property Crew. Property Crew is list of objects with properties OfficerId and OfficerName.

Comment: Can you add an example of such a Crew list in your question?

Comment: I added. See question

Comment: >>> print(result[0].SpacehipId)
1
>>> print(result[1].Crew[0].OfficerName)
Michel Smith